# Unresolved Extern

Tags: extern, unresolved-external

I am using `extern` in my project for variables and functions so that i can share that with my other source files in future.

How am i trying to use it?

I had made a "Header file" for `Declaration` of Variables and functions by the name `dec.h`

There is another file by the name `def.c` in which I had `Defined` those Variables and functions. `def.c` file includes `dec.h` file.

Now in my `main` program, when I include `dec.h` file only and try to build the program, compiler warns as `Unresolved Extern [My function names]`.

Am I trying to do it the wrong way? I have read to use extern that way in the following thread [How do I use extern to share variables between source files in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above procedure was right, The problem was that I haven't included the `def.c`  to my project files.